# What can I do whan Visual Studio is not finding referenced package?

Tags: windows-phone, visual-studio-2017, emulation, bots

I am facing this problem whe developing bots:

[image: Error Message]

I am beginner and not so sure about the references section. I assume it has to basically be the same as the installed nuget-packages list, so I checked but didn't see any divergences between those two lists.

Or does this message mean somethoing entirely different?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak german fluently, so I will explain the menuing in english : go to Project -> Add Reference and try to find packages you instalated with nugget (sometimes references arent added automaticaly), and check also for package version compatibility (some problems can be resolved by changing the framework version as well)

Comment: I did that. But for the System.IdentityModel.Token.awt everything is up to date. When I try to install this package's newest Version Nuget Manager complains about conflicts, so I left it with version 5.1.4

Comment: And the error above occurs, whichever bot framework sample I run on the Windows phone emulator, so it has to be something IDE specific, not project settings. Those projects can't be all corrupted. Ist das mal wieder schön :)